# Missing elements when performing a search on "Local SharePoint Results" source

Tags: web-part, search-results, result-source

I have a library with 4 documents returned by a specific term (when using the search box at the top of the library).
But when I try to perform the same search on a webpart linked (by default) to the "Local SharePoint Results" source, I get only 2 results.

All these elements (documents) have a unique name.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are seeing unexpected query results you should check:

- Is Duplicate Trimming happeneing, turn it off in the web part.
- Are the permissions getting in the way, try again with an account that has rights to the content
- Has the content been crawled (this is not your case, but here for completeness)

Comment: Seems like it was the duplicate thing. Yet none of these documents seem duplicates. I'll ask my client about that. Thanks!